# how to use multiple optional arguments in typescript

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters

In my typescript/node.js code, I have a function with two optional parameters as follows:

```
export const func1 = (num: Number, name: string, obj?: Params, credentials?: Credentials) => {
```

where `Params` is something user-defined, and `Credentials` is from `import { Credentials } from '@aws-sdk/types';`

However, when I call `func1` as follows:

```
func1(
      1,
      'Stack',
      {
        name: 'Stack',
        age: 14,
      },
      credentials
    );
```

where `credentials` is of type `Credentials` I get an error saying that `func1 expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4` - I can understand why this would happen if only one optional argument was allowed, but does anyone know how I can include 2 optional arguments for `func1`?

Comment: Worth note: `number` and `Number` are different types. `number` is a numeric primitive (like `1`) and `Number` is an object created with `new Number(...)`.

Comment: Nice spotting! I've been working in TypeScript for a while and completely skipped over the fact that they used `Number`, which would cause an error when trying to pass the function.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript (and JavaScript for that matter), `number` and `Number` are two different things. Whereas `number` is the type for a normal integer or floating point, `Number` is a constructor used to initialise a new integer or floating point with the `number` type. So, you can change it to this:

```ts
export const func1 = (num: number, name: string, obj?: Params, credentials?: Credentials) => {}
```

and all should work as planned.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error - I think the core issue is that for some reason they only accept one optional argument

Comment: If I change the type of the first argument around I'm still getting the error ```func1 expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - just a matter of running `yarn build` after adding the new optional argument

Comment: Consider using `tsc -w` for incremental compilation.